# Visualization Issues using Running Total on an Appended Query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Using PowerBI linked to two separate Access Databases.

I have two datasets containing cost estimates. The cost estimates in Dataset 1 run through 2054; the cost estimates in Dataset 2 run through 2074. I used the Append function to join the two tables together and used the Quick Measure for Running Total to create values for cumulative cost by year. I charted this measure and noticed a significant decrease between 2054 and 2055 and was able to determine that the decrease is the cumulative value for Dataset 1. Does anybody know any ways to fix this?

Roughly explained:

```
Dataset 1 through 2054 totals to 4.5M.
Dataset 2 through 2054 totals to 3M
Dataset 2 through 2055 totals to 3.25M
Appended Dataset through 2054 totals to 7.5M
Appended Dataset through 2055 totals 3.25M instead of the expected 7.75M
```

I think the issue might be caused by Dataset 1 not having a value for 2055 or after, but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

The measure I'm using is:

```
Cumulative Cost = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('AppendedQuery'[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('AppendedQuery'[Year]),
        ISONORAFTER('AppendedQuery'[Year], MAX('AppendedQuery'[Year]), DESC)
    )
)
```

[ETA: Picture to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIygs.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data in tabular format rather than explain it. Its now difficult to understand/read data/

Comment: @mkRabbani I added a picture that hopefully clears things up.

Comment: According to your sample data, you are getting correct result for 2055 and 2056 as they are only available in data set 2. Why/how you are expecting 9 for 2055? 2055 is only available in Data set 2 and value is 5.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the point of Append. I'm under the impression that Appended tables should be treated as one dataset. If that's true, then the cumulative value through 2055 is 9 and the cumulative value through 2056 is 10. Am I misunderstanding how Appended tables work?

Comment: Append is UNION ALL in SQL.

Comment: Then why should I not be getting 9 in 2055? If I sum up the values in the combined dataset that occur in years prior to 2055, I get 9. In other words, if you spent $1 per year for 4 years on one credit card, and $1 per year for 6 years on a second credit card, how much total did you spend at the end of the fifth and sixth year? You spent $9 through year 5 and $10 through year 6.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your **Dataset 1**-

[image]

Here is your **Dataset 2**-

[image]

Here is your final Dataset after appending Dataset 1 & 2

[image]

And finally, here is the output when you are adding column Year and Cumulative Cost to a table visual. As standard PBI behavior, this is just grouping data using column Year and and applying SUM to the column Cumulative Cost.

[image]

The calculations are simple-

```
2051 > 1 + 1 = 2
2052 > 2 + 2 = 4
2053 > 3 + 3 = 6
2054 > 4 + 4 = 8
2055 >     5 = 5
2056 >     6 = 6
```

**=========================**

**Solution for your case:**
I already said in the comments that the solution current data will be not a standard one and will consider fixed $1 per year per department. But if you are happy with this static consideration, you can apply these following steps to achieve your required output-

**Step-1** Create a **Custom Column** as below (Adjust the table name as per yours)-

```
this_year_spent = IF('Dataset 3'[Cumulative Cost] = BLANK(),0,1)
```

**Step-2** Create the following **Measure-**

```
cumulative = 

VAR current_year = MIN('Dataset 3'[Year])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Dataset 3'[this_year_spent]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Dataset 3'),
        'Dataset 3'[Year] <= current_year
    )
)
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if there's some sort of misunderstanding here, but I need it to equal 9 in 2055 and 10 in 2056. My issue is that PowerBI does not sum this up correctly. Again, if I spend $1 per year on Credit Card 1, from 2051 through 2054, I have spent 4 dollars at the end of 2054. If I *ALSO* spend $1 per year on Credit Card 2, but from 2051 through 2056, then at the end of 2056, I have spent $6 on Credit Card 2. I have spent $10 total at the end of 2056. PowerBI would suggest that I've only spent $6 total, which is incorrect. Is there any sort of workaround here?

Comment: No issue with power bi. Its all in our calculation. Now tell me- how you consider 2 is correct for 2051? And how it should be 9 for 2055? Just explain the logic.

Comment: After appending 2 tables, there are 2 rows for 2051. Do you need just 1 row to consider among those 2 rows for 2051?

Comment: The data comes from two departments within the same organization (they function independently, which is why their data is stored separately), but the money comes from the same bank account. So if each department spends $1 in 2051, at the end of the year, the total organization has spent $2. At the end of 2054, each department has spent $4, for a total of $8 spent by the organization from 2051 through the end of 2054. In 2055, one of the departments ceases to exist, but the other department still spends $1. This means the organization spends $8 through the end of 2054, plus $1 in 2055= $9 total

Comment: The problem is in the way you are storing your data. You are already storing cumulative data per year but per department wise! And now, you wants to calculate cumulative amount again, but for both department together! Either you have to change your data storing way or the calculation way. Better is to keep the raw data like $1 per year and calculate the cumulative amount in Query/Report. This is better option as some year a department can also spent $2. And bad option is to consider all value as $1 to calculate the cumulative value. This is bad as the $1 per month and department will be fixed.

Comment: Hi @AlexM, I also add the solution for your case in the updated answer. Please check.